# Битрикс 1C - сложно ли его изучать и что он из себя представляет?

Tags: 1с, битрикс

Добрый день! У меня вопросы к тем кто работал и изучал CMS Битрикс 1с.

1. Что представляет из себя эта система (Прочитал что там предпочтение идет файловому наполнению содержания, а не через БД. Ядро закрытое для изменения. Слишком навороченная)?
2. Еще некоторые пишут что это фреймворк, другие что CMS, так что есть правильно?
3. Сложно ли изучить не знающему о Битрексе ничего, имея в багаже знания только PHP, HTML, Javascript?
4. И последний вопрос, можно ли где-то скачать бесплатное Битрикс, чтобы практиковаться на нем без ограничения 30 дней?

Буду благодарен, за исчерпывающие ответы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Типичный СУК, общего назначения. Данные в базе, настройки в файлах... Субъективно по "продвинутости" сравнима с Друпалом. Много платных и бесплатных модулей, большое сообщество, хорошая поддержка. Хорошо интегрируется с другими продуктами 1С. Удобна для создания магазинов.
2. Это СУК, который можно использовать как фреймворк. Но если оно вам надо, то лучше, например, Yii использовать.
3. Люди разные, опыт разный... Порог вхождения, для меня был выше, чем даже на Рельсы и Друпал, но когда "врубился" -- там всё просто оказалось.
4. Дык на официальном сайте....

Comment: На официальном сайте, это тут? http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/download/ Там вроде 30-ти дневка только есть... И что за Виртуальная машина BitrixVM - это аналог WMware что ли? Или что-то вроде денвера?

Comment: 1. Невнимательно прочитал вопрос : ). Можно, наверное, найти ломаную версию, но где -- не знаю. И мне кажется, что 30ти дней достаточно для принятия решения о покупке. А если решите связываться -- покупать придётся.
2. Это и есть ВМварная виртуалка. "«1С-Битрикс: Виртуальная машина» реализована с использованием технологий виртуализации VMware и может быть использована в любых решениях VMware, предназначенных для cloud computing."

Comment: А оно вам, вообще на кой надо? Просто-так "поизучать" или для дела?

Comment: Ну вообще я устраиваюсь на работу. Перед тем как устроиться мне дали четыре тестовых задания на знания верстки страниц, на знание грамотного проектирования баз данных, на знание php и mysql и последнее задание на знание javascript и ajax. Я их выполнил, на работу берут, но в итоге оказалось, что на работе мне придется работать с 1с Битрикс. Потому и думаю, что придется таскать с работы свои проекты и размещать на своем компе, чтобы ковыряться, разбираться, что к чему работает... Потому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Тогда советую узнать в какой комплектации и для чего используется Б, после чего развернуть соответствующую 30ти дневную версию у себя и "ковыряться". Кстати, для лицензированных пользователей у них есть закрытый раздел на форуме, где много полезного -- поговорите с работодателем, возможно он организует вам доступ.

Comment: Что-то я поставил BitrixVM скаченную с офицального сайта. А там операционка CentOS и логин и пароль требует. Пробовал root с пустым паролем, не помогло. Кто подскажет, что там вводить?

Comment: Ссылка со страницы скачки: :)
http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/forums/forum32/topic51573/